# How to normalize semantically same language tags? [cldr]

Tags: iana, cldr, ietf-bcp-47

I am currently browsing the cldr-common-42 database and I find the use of language tags a bit confusing.
For example, the tag `ar-EG` is used for translations in Egyptian Arabic. However, when looking for what "Egyptian Arabic" is in other languages, I need to look up the code `arz`.

Is there any way to normalize such cases in a programatic way (for example, a neat database containing both forms)? Also, which form should be preferred for what context?

I have looked online for databases that contain both forms, but only found databases where they were not linked in any way.

Glad for anyone who can clarify things for me and maybe point me at some resources for normalization!